# Confluence giving weird exception "Invalid file name for use with -Xloggc" while running on ubuntu EC2

Tags: ubuntu, confluence

I have installed atlassian-confluence-5.6.3.tar.gz on my Ubuntu server hosted on Amazon EC2.
Whenever I am trying to start confluence after un-tarring the above mentioned file it is showing like:
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
To run Confluence in the foreground, start the server with start-confluence.sh -fg
executing as current user
If you encounter issues starting up Confluence, please see the Installation guide at http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Confluence+Installation+Guide

Server startup logs are located in /home/ubuntu/atlassian-confluence-5.6.4/logs/catalina.out
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/ubuntu/atlassian-confluence-5.6.4
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/ubuntu/atlassian-confluence-5.6.4
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/ubuntu/atlassian-confluence-5.6.4/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/ubuntu/atlassian-confluence-5.6.4/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/ubuntu/atlassian-confluence-5.6.4/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_PID:    /home/ubuntu/atlassian-confluence-5.6.4/work/catalina.pid
Tomcat started.
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
But on checking I can see that Confluence have not started.
On checking the file /home/ubuntu/atlassian-confluence-5.6.4/logs/catalina.out I can see the following error:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid file name for use with -Xloggc: Filename can only contain the characters [A-Z][a-z][0-9]-_.%[p|t] but it has been /home/ubuntu/atlassian-confluence-5.6.4/logs/gc-2014-11-04_20:26:52.log
Note %p or %t can only be used once
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Worked like magic ... Thanks a lot Martin for the response.

Comment: @MartinRöbert Can you add your reply at the Answer Section so that I can nominate it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same problem on Debian 7/JDK8 - Workaround would be to edit setenv.sh: change the date call in -Xloggc section from `date +%F_%T` to `date +%F`. Afterwards run `touch <CONFLUENCE_HOME>/logs/gc-2014-11-05.log` (substitute the date). Confluence should start now.